# In cassandra cqlsh, how do I select from map<ascii, ascii> in a table?

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cqlsh, thrift-protocol

Basically here is how my table is set up:

```
CREATE TABLE points (
  name ascii,
  id varint,
  attributes map<ascii, ascii>,
  PRIMARY KEY (name, id)
)
```

and if I run the following SELECT statement I get this returned:

`SELECT id, attributes from points limit 5;`

```
   id | attributes
  ----+------------------------------------------
    1 | {STATION/Name: ABC, Type: 2, pFreq: 101}
    2 | {STATION/Name: ABC, Type: 1, pFreq: 101}
    3 | {STATION/Name: DEF, Type: 1, pFreq: 103}
    4 | {STATION/Name: GHI, Type: 2, pFreq: 105}
    5 | {STATION/Name: GHI, Type: 1, pFreq: 105}
```

What I would like to do is be able to form a WHERE clause based on info inside of attributes. Something like the following statement:

`SELECT id FROM points WHERE name = 'NAME' AND attributes['pFreq'] = 101;`

However, when I run this I get the following error:

`Bad Request: line 1:56 no viable alternative at input '['`

I looked at [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections) discussion and it seems as though it is not supported yet, is this true? Or is there a way to filter on the attributes information?

Here are the versions I am working with:

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.7 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes is true, instead you can use CONTAINS:

```
SELECT * FROM points WHERE attributes CONTAINS 101;
```

Comment: When I use CONTAINS I get the following error:

Bad Request: line 1:104 no viable alternative at input 'CONTAINS'

Comment: can you use map<text,text> instead of ascii?, or is mandatory use ascii?

Comment: create index on points (attributes) returns "Bad Request: Indexes on collections are no yet supported". So this seems like the root of my problems. Not sure if there is a workaround for it at all, outside of splitting pFreq out into its own part of the schema.

Comment: Can you upgrade your cassandra version to cassandra greather than 2.1?? I created a index in dsc-cassandra-2.1.4, and works fine

Comment: Thats up to my developers I suppose, lol. But thanks for the info. I don't know why they would schema tables in such a way we can't read items before the capability exists. Oh well!